# Yodlee Interactive - coblogin API to authenticate - errorCode 415

Tags: javascript, node.js, yodlee

I guys,

I'm pretty new to javascript/nodeJS.

I try to connect to Yodlee API. Here is my code:

```
var needle = require('needle');

var url = 'https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0​/authenticate/coblogin';
var data = { 
    cobrandLogin:'sbXXX',
    cobrandPassword:'XXX'
};
var options = {
  headers: { 'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
};


var post = needle.post(url, data, options, function(err, resp) {
  if (err) {
        return console.error('upload failed:', err);
     }
    console.log('\n\nUpload successful!  Server responded with:\n', resp.body.toString('utf8'));
});
```

I get the following response :

```
Upload successful!  Server responded with:
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Errors xmlns="http://namespace.yodlee.com/pfm/2009/Error">
    <Error>
        <errorCode>415</errorCode>
        <errorDetail>system_error</errorDetail>
    </Error>
</Errors>
```

The yodlee error code list (http://developer.yodlee.com/FAQs/Error_Codes#List_of_Error_Codes) say:

```
Problem Updating Account(415): We could not update your account because the <SITE_NAME> is experiencing technical difficulties.
```

I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong.

Can you please help ?

Thx
Bibi

Answer (score 2):

There can be below issues for getting 415 (system error)  –

1. The REST URL is not correct. (this can also cause 418)
2. The content type of the parameter sent is not correct. Please make sure to use “application/x-www-form-urlencoded” to POST the request.
3. There can be a problem with the URL having an extra zero-width space, which can be the result of cutting/pasting the path directly from the Yodlee APIdocumentation page.
       There is an extra zero character space after the path in the html, that is invisible to text editors.

The 415 error code present at http://developer.yodlee.com/FAQs/Error_Codes#List_of_Error_Codes represent the error coming while trying to link an account using Yodlee's services.

Comment: They should fix that third thing. Super annoying.